# pivot table Datagrid c# column header same as first row

Tags: c#, sql, pivot

I have a request from a client that is perplexing me, they want what they call a pivot table, I call a table. The top row is the same as the first column data so it looks something like this:

[image: Table]

I save all the data to one table regardless of the data that it is, Demographic_Question INT, Response nvchar. I also use a separate table to get the demographic text.

I think I have the text part down I just seem to be having a issue with the best way to get the average data for each statement.

Thanks!
Tim

Edit:
Table Structure: ID int, Respondent_ID int, Survey_ID uniqueidentifier, Demographic_Questions int, Respons nvarchar.

I have not made any attempts at this time I am not sure how to average a count against a different count in SQL. I am using SQL server and c#... Thinking about it I could count(ID) where = demographic 1 and then count(ID) where response = 1 and demographic = 1 get that average then do it for the next, I was thinking something more dynamic. 
Just not sure how to proceed

Second Edit This is what I have come up with so far just need the data part:
[image]